# Binomial computation: Probability of winning at least 175 games out of 900 trials

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

We roll a die, if it stops on **1**, we win, if not we lose.

So we have $\frac{1}{6}$ chance of winning. **What is the probability of winnign at least 175 times out of 900 rolls ?**
We can see this as a repetition of independent games so we can use Binomial distribution. I want to find $$P(\text{Win} \geq 175)$$ but the binomial formula will only give me $P(\text{Win} = 175)$ so I will need to do that for $176,..900$.
Or I can also compute $1-P(\text{Win} < 175)$ but I still need to do 175 calculations..
How can I do it ?

Comment: I'm afraid that's the only way to do it - with such big numbers.

Comment: That's in an exam so.. there must be a formula

Comment: It should be $\binom{900}{175}\cdot 1/6^{175}$

Comment: @yanko that's the probability of winning exactly $175$ times.

Comment: The normal approximation should be quite good.

Comment: That's the only way. However, the probability can be approximated using the Central limit theorem.

Comment: @Dan no wait, if you want to win exactly 175 times then you need to multiply by $(5/6)^{900-175}$ no??

Comment: using the CLT ?
and yanko why you don't multiply by $(\frac{5}{6})^{900-175}$

Comment: @yanko, that's right

Comment: @Dan , So is $\binom{900}{175}\cdot 1/6^{175}$ the right answer or am I missing something??

Comment: @GabrielRamon.  I see you deleted your Answer. It showed a worthwhile simplification and the correct numerical answer.

Comment: I wrote a little program in MATLAB and I have around $1.5$ %. Is this the result @GabrielRamon also found ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two methods are easier than computing with the binomial PDF by hand:

**(1) Use software.** Suppose the binomial random variable is $W \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=1000, p = 1/6).$ You seek $P(W \ge 175) = 1 - P(X \le 174) = 0.2515.$ Using R statistical
software where `pbinom` is a binomial CDF and `dbinom` is a binomial PDF, we get the exact answer.

```
 1 - pbinom(174, 1000, 1/6)
 ## 0.2514526
 k = 175:1000;  sum(dbinom(k, 1000, 1/6))
 ## 0.2514526
```

**Use a normal approximation:**  $\mu = E(W) = np = 1000(1/6) =  166.6667$
and $\sigma = SD(W) = \sqrt{np(1-p)} = \sqrt{1000(1/6)(5/6)} =  11.7851.$ Then
$$P(X \ge 175) = P(X > 174.5) = 
P\left(\frac{W - \mu}{\sigma} > \frac{174.5 - 166.68}{11.7851}\right)\\
\approx P(Z > 0.6647) \approx 0.2531,$$
where $Z$ is standard normal and the approximate probability can be
obtained using printed standard normal tables. (You will probably not get *exactly* the same result because without interpolation you will enter the printed
table with 0.66 instead of 0.6647. In any case one should not expect better
than two place accuracy using a normal approximation to a binomial distribution.)

The figure below shows the exact binomial distribution (vertical black bars)
along with the 'best fitting' normal distribution. The relevant probability
is to the right of the dotted red line.

[image]

Comment: I have 900 trials not 1000, I think it changes the result a lot

Comment: Right about that. But my intention was to illustrate the _methods,_ not to work your exact hwk problem. Some statistical calculators can do both binomial and normal computations (if you are not using a software package). The normal approximation should be quite good for 900--as it is for 1000; I suspect that is the method you're expected to use.

Comment: But why the probability of winning at least 100 times is not close to 1 on your graph ?

Comment: It is: _All_ of the bars shown on the graph are for 100 or more Wins. (If I had made a graph that goes all the way down to 0 and all the way up to $n,$ then the bars would almost merge together in the central part of the graph where almost all of the probability lies.)

Comment: Oh yes i'm sorry.. Because it is **at least** 100, I need to sum up all the bars that are at the right of 100 which is around 1.

Comment: And why using the normal approximation, the expected value is $np$ and not $p$ ? Because the expected value of Bernoulli($\frac{1}{6}$) is $\frac{1}{6}$. So when using the normal approximation, I need to find the expected value of the sum of all bernoulli games and not just 1?

Comment: But you are computing binomial $W$ with $E(W) = np$ not Bernoulli with mean $p.$ The 'best fitting normal' is usually taken to be the one that matches binomial mean and SD with the normal mean and SD. [But slight variations of that (giving slightly better approximations) can sometimes be found. (Not of much interest nowadays when software can easily give _exact_ results.)]